# Trying to plot shape when value of the indicator ema first increases or decreases

Tags: pine-script

I am new to pine and am having trouble with this. its probably syntax or improper calculation. Code as follows:

```
buySignal = input.bool(true,title='Buy Signal')
sellSignal = input.bool(true,title='Sell Signal')

plotshape(buySignal ? lenema > lenema[1] and lenema[1] < lenema[2]: na,title='Buy Shape', style=shape.triangleup,color=color.green, location=location.belowbar,size=size.large)

plotshape(sellSignal ? lenema < lenema[1] and lenema[1] > lenema[2]: na,title='Sell Shape',style=shape.triangledown,color=color.red, location=location.abovebar,size=size.large)
```

Trying to plot shape when value of the indicator ema first increases or decreases

previous code is:

```
// RSI code
rsi = ta.rsi(close, len)
plot(rsi, color=color.new(color.white, 0), linewidth=3)
plot(rsi)


lenema = input.int(200, minval=1, title='RSI EMA Length')
out = ta.ema(rsi, lenema)
col = out >= out[1] ? color.lime : color.red
plot(out, title='RSI EMA', color=col, linewidth=2)
```

Comment: I forgot to clarify that the code is compiling but no triangles are being displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are comparing the `length`. `lenema` is `input.int` and it will be constant so that's why your comparison doesn't work.

You probably want to have:

```
plotshape(buySignal ? (out > out[1] and out[1] < out[2]) : na,title='Buy Shape', style=shape.triangleup,color=color.green, location=location.belowbar,size=size.large)

plotshape(sellSignal ? (out < out[1] and out[1] > out[2]) : na,title='Sell Shape',style=shape.triangledown,color=color.red, location=location.abovebar,size=size.large)
```

Print triangles on the RSI line:

```
plotshape((buySignal and (out > out[1] and out[1] < out[2])) ? rsi : na,title='Buy Shape', style=shape.triangleup,color=color.green, location=location.absolute,size=size.large)

plotshape((sellSignal and (out < out[1] and out[1] > out[2])) ? rsi : na,title='Sell Shape',style=shape.triangledown,color=color.red, location=location.abovebar,size=size.large)
```

Comment: I also switched the location above bar and below bar to top and bottom as the above bar and below bar printed them well above my graph. The triangles printed at the value of the price rather than the RSI ema. I'm glad its working now though.

Comment: You can set `location=location.absolute` and use `rsi` as your price level. That way the triangles will be printed on the RSI line. Please see my edit. I haven't tested it but it should work.

Comment: Thanks. There is something more to the logic I am getting wrong. When I do that, the arrows print constantly on every bar at the bottom of the graph.  Its probably because the code is overlaid on an already created script. I will try to put it by itself and see how it goes.

Comment: also using location.above or below bar causes the triangles to print higher than the line

Comment: This is my indicator header. Is some input missing?

Comment: indicator(title='RSI EMA Filtered Entries', shorttitle='RSI EMA Filtered Entries', overlay = false)

Comment: Solved it.    Solution as follows:

Answer (score 0):

[Screen capture because it was easier than pasting the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeUOl.png)